# I tried writing a code that generates anagrams of a given word. it throws an error for input size>6

Tags: java, arraylist

The code works fine for words having length=6. But when i enter a word of 7 letters it throws this stack overflow error.Is there a way to resolve this?In this code the generator function swaps the "i'th" element of the word with the last element.example->car. In the first pass it will generate 'rac' and in the second 'cra'.Now these 2 new words are passed as parameters to the 'check' function. It is to be noted that when the 'generator' function is called for the first time, the input word is added to the arraylist. Thereafter,the words are added to the arraylist if and only if that word is not present in it i.e. the generator function is called only when a new word is generated. So now, wen 'rac' is generated and passed into 'check',it returns false.This means that the word is not present and generator function is called. Now 'rac' generates 'car' and 'rca'
But 'car' is already present. So it will not be passed as parameter to the 'generator' function.The presence of a word in the arraylist acts as the terminating condition.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class progx
{
   static ArrayList<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      progx ob = new progx();
      ob.input();
   }

   void input() throws IOException // this function takes the input
   { // from user and calls "generator" function
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.println("enter word");
      String s = in.readLine();
      progx obj = new progx();
      obj.generator(s); // call 'generator' function
   }

   void generator(String s) throws IOException
   {
      progx ob = new progx();
      String output = "";
      boolean c = false;
      word.add(s); // adds the word to arraylist

      int i, j, l = s.length(), l2 = l - 1;
      char temp;
      char[] b = new char[l];
      for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
      {
         b[i] = s.charAt(i); // initializing each element in array
      } // with the ith character of the input string

      i = 0; // re-initializing 'i' for the while loop
      while (i < l)
      {
         temp = b[i]; // swapping ith character with last element
         b[i] = b[l2];
         b[l2] = temp;
         output = (ob.convertArray(b));// storing the new word in 'output'
         c = ob.check(output);// checking whether the elemnt is present in
                              // arraylist

         if (c == false)// if the word is not present, then call the 'generator'
                        // function
         {
            System.out.println(output);
            ob.generator(output);
         }

         for (j = 0; j < l; j++) // re-initialising the array as the swapping
         {
            b[j] = s.charAt(j);
         } // might change the position characters
         i++; // of the original input String "s"
      }
   }

   String convertArray(char[] s) // array converter- converts array to string
   {
      String n = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
      {
         n = n + s[i];
      }
      return n;
   }

   boolean check(String output) // function that checks presence
   { // of the generated word in the array
      boolean present = word.contains(output);
      return present;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please intend your code.

Comment: If I were a Java compiler I would yield an error about indentation.

Comment: Recursion.... You must be expecting this error... Check if it is going into an infinite loop anywhere... Debug it ....

Comment: Tip: Your `convertArray` method is not required. You can use one of `String`'s constructors, in particular the one that has a `char[]` parameter.

Comment: how is this even working for length=6 , class has to be public.

Comment: Please post your **entire** error message (with trace back).

Comment: But as per code, he is using main method, so seems like running from same class. Sure it is possible if run from another class. :)

Comment: @Batty Indeed, and it's weird, but I've seen SO (maybe TOO?) much...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.withResult(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeLoop(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)

Comment: @PM77-1 up here is the entire error message

Answer (score 0):

The way you are currently generating the anagrams is giving you the Stack Overflow error because your methods are nesting far too deep. In Java, you have a stack representing all your method calls and such. It has a limited amount of memory, and when you hit that cap it overflows.

Because your method calls are nested so deeply, (They are nested by like `n!` where `n` is the number of letters in the word) you're calling the methods over and over again, but because of the nesting, they can't be removed from the stack. Thus, you eventually hit a point where you run out of memory.

I would rethink the algorithm you are using to generate these anagrams (unless you're ok with it hitting a cap on some machines, mine broke at a length of 8).

Comment: could please suggest an alternative approach??

Comment: or is there a way to increase the stack size??

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class rec 
{

  char a[] = {
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd'
  };

  char temp = ' ';

  void Anagram(int i) 
  {
    if (i < a.length) 
    {
      temp = a[0];
      a[0] = a[i];
      a[i] = temp;
      Anagram1(0);
      Anagram(i + 1);
    } else
      return;
  }

  void Anagram1(int r) 
  {
    if (r < a.length - 1) 
    {
      Anagram2(1);
      Anagram1(r + 1);
    } else
      return;
  }
  void Anagram2(int j) 
  {
    if (j < a.length - 1)
    {
      temp = a[j + 1];
      a[j + 1] = a[j];
      a[j] = temp;
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
      Anagram2(j + 1);
    } else
      return;
  }

 public static void main(String args[]) 
 {
     rec r =new rec();
    r.Anagram(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code consistently.  Also, this is more convoluted than it needs to be.

Comment: @gwaigh pls be specific